# Suppose that $f : U \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ has continuous first partial derivatives.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, multivariable-calculus, contest-math

Let U be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and C a compact subset of U.
Suppose that $f : U \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ has continuous first partial derivatives. Prove that f is Lipschitz on C.

Thoughts: Let $M$ be an upperbound for $|\nabla f|$. For arbitrary $a,b\in C$, if $a$ and $b$ are connected, we can apply the mean value theorem to get $|f(a)-f(b)|=|\nabla f(c)\cdot(a-b)|\le M|(a-b)|$ by Cauchy-Schwarz (where $c$ is on the line segment from $a$ to $b$. But what if $a$ and $b$ aren't connected (I think compactness doesn't imply path connectedness)

Comment: Most surely compactness does not imply path connectedness: the set $\{0,1\}$ is compact! In fact, the set $C$ could well be totally disconnected, and in that case so your argument proves nothing! :-)

Comment: When you say $a,b$ are connected, do you mean that the segment $[a,b]$ is contained in $U$? I guess so, since the only MVT I know in this context requires that.

Comment: @julien: yes :)

Comment: Are you sure the question does not say that $U$ is convex then?

Comment: No. it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this, you can always find an arc-connected compact subset $K\subseteq U$ such that $C\subseteq K$. Then do your argument for $K$ and, since you can restrict the conclusion to $C$, you are happy.

Comment: If K is arc-connected, does the mean value theorem apply? What argument do you have in mind?

Comment: I was just showing that *if* the argument in the question worked, then there was no problem dealing with unconnected compact sets. It doesn't though :-)

Comment: I have the feeling that $U$ should be convex, so that we can take $K$ to be the closed convex hull of $C$ in your argument. And then apply the MVT.

Comment: If I were to prove this, I would should that *(i)* if $C$ is a union of finitely many compact subsets on each of which $f$ is Lipschitz, then $f$ is Lipschitz on $C$; *(ii)* $C$ can be covered by finitely many closed discs contained in $U$, and *(iii)* $f$ is Lipschitz on each closed disc contained in $U$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. The idea is to enlarge $C$ so that it still remains in $U$, and is 'locally connected by straight lines'.

Let $\delta = \frac{1}{2}\sup \{ r | B(x, r) \subset U, \forall x \in C \}$. Since $C$ is compact, we have $\delta > 0$, and $\overline{B}(x,\delta) \subset U$ for all $x \in C$. Furthermore, if we let $C' = \cup_{x \in C} \overline{B}(x,\delta)$, then $C' \subset U$ and $C'$ is also compact.

(To see that $C'$ is compact, let $\phi: \mathbb{R}^n \to [0,\infty)$ be given by $\phi(x) = \min_{c \in C} \|x-c\|$. $\phi$ is continuous and $C' = \phi^{-1}[0,\delta]$. Hence $C'$ is closed, and trivially bounded. Since we are in $\mathbb{R}^n$, it follows that $C'$ is compact.)

Let $L$ be an upper bound for $\|\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}\|$ for $x \in C'$ and let $M$ be an upper bound for $|f(x)|$ for $x \in C'$. 
Now let $L' = \max(L,\frac{2M}{\delta})$.

Then $f$ is Lipschitz of rank $L'$ on $C$. To see this, let $x,y \in C$. If $\|x-y\| < \delta$, then by construction $y \in B(x,\delta) \subset C' \subset U$, and hence we have $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq L \|x-y\| \leq L' \|x-y\| $. If $\|x-y\| \geq \delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq 2M = \frac{2M}{\delta} \delta \leq L' \|x-y\|$.